# How to control Size of Jquery mobile control group?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, size

I'm using jquery mobile and I have a control group which is being rendered like this:

[image]

However if you go on this page, http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/textinputs/index.html, u'll see on the top a control group like the following;

[image]

I'm still trying to know how jquery makes its control group smaller in size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the jQM Demo they have added additional CSS

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/_assets/css/jqm-docs.css

Placing the class on the `<ul>` element

```
class="localnav"
```

Example:

```
<ul data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="localnav">
    <li><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn-active">Basics</a></li>
    <li><a href="options.html" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">Options</a></li>
    <li><a href="methods.html" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">Methods</a></li>
    <li><a href="events.html" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">Events</a></li>
</ul>​
```

and adding this CSS

```
.localnav {
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.localnav li {
    float:left;
}
.localnav .ui-btn-inner { 
    padding: .6em 10px; 
    font-size:80%; 
}
```

Should get the results you want but it's really setting the font size that does it

Answer (score 2):

In the controlgroup you add **data-mini="true"** like this:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to wrap your buttons inside a container like this:

```
<div class="buttonsHere">
   <button class="myButton" id="search">Search</button>
   <button class="myButton" id="latest">Latest</button>
   <button class="myButton" id="top">Top</button>
</div>
```

Then, in your stylesheet do like this:

```
.buttonsHere.ui-btn-text {
    font-size: 20px;    
}
```

Let me know if this works as I cannot test it here. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you digg the code by using firebug then you can came to know that the childrens of ul is like this ul > li > a > span > ***span*** . And in the final span tag you will have the css as follows.

```
.localnav .ui-btn-inner {
font-size: 80%;
}
```

If you change the font-size to some what less % or in px , you can get your required size.
I think the following thing will work

```
$('ul li li a span span').css('font-size',60%');
```

*I haven't done any example .. please ignore this if it not work for you*